# Service layer design

Tags: java, service, architecture

I'm working on a pet project, which is basicly 3-layer application (UI, service, DAO). At current state we don't use DI frameworks and I have a question about architecture. Suppose we've got Order, Goods and Manager entities, equal DAO classes and so do services. According to BL, OrderService should be aware of either DAOManager and DAOGoods or ManagerService and GoodsService. Keeping in mind that we still don't use Spring/Guice, which way of connections seems more appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're not using a DI framework, the design of your classes should still allow for DI later, i.e. make all your dependencies constructor arguments.

This is just good design. An object states its dependencies upfront, forcing them to be provided at instantiation time, thereby allowing the classes to be independent and allows for easy mocking and unit testing.

In your example, OrderService should provide one of the following constructors, depending on your implementation style):

- OrderService(DAOManager, DAOGoods)
- OrderService(ManagerService, GoodsService)
- OrderService(IManagerService, IGoodsService) - [interfaces not concretes]

You will need manage the creation and fulfilling of these objects and their dependencies manually without a DI framework, which can get tricky. I would highly recommend a builder pattern coupled with a service locator in the absence of a DI container.